# Custom Control with Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks

I am new to WPF and developing few custom controls. I am always come across memory leaks in my custom control. My control was not removed from memory even though it was removed from Visual Tree.

Is there any design pattern we need to follow to create custom control without memory leak in WPF?

Or can we use IDisposable to do this? But in this case, the Dispose() method not invoking implicitly. Seems .net Frameowrk buil in WPF Controls like Button, TextBox are not IDisposable. But they are not memory leaky.

Any quick advice is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jawahar

Comment: RE `IDisposable` implementation; `Dispose()` is not implicitly called, you need to call it yourself. RE memory leaks; are you sure you've removed all references to your `UserControl` (including event handlers)? If not, the Garbage Collector may not have deemed it ready for cleanup. Also, can you post any code to provide a sample of your problem?

Comment: @WPF Lover How fo you know that your control is still in memory?

Comment: @Dimitry : I am profiling with red gate ANTS

Answer (score 0):

A component that has an event registered, such as Loaded, will not be unloaded until all events are unregistered.
Always remember to unregister your events when you don't need them anymore.

It may also be the case of a thread still running.

Comment: Thanks, May I know which is the right place to unregister the events. Can we use Unloaded event? But we cannot expect Unloaded will call only when the instance is about to Dispose(). Conisder my Custom Control is in Tab Item.